# How do I adjust the line height in flutter_markdown?

Tags: flutter, markdown

I wrote this minimal example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Markdown(
            selectable: true,
            styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet.fromTheme(ThemeData(
                textTheme: const TextTheme(
                    bodyText2: TextStyle(height: 1.2, fontSize: 14.0)))),
            data: 'one\n\ntwo\n\nthree'));
  }
}
```

The problem is that the lines are space out about 4 times what they should be, as shown on the **left** in the image below.

[image: with (left) and without (right) 'selectable']

Adjusting `height` and a bunch of other style sheet properties I tried does not fix the line spacing. However, changing `selectable` ([docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_markdown/latest/flutter_markdown/MarkdownWidget/selectable.html)) to `false` and restarting the app fixes it, as shown on the **right**. This also makes the `height` property work as expected.

I've tested this with `flutter run -d linux` and `flutter run -d chrome` with the same results. I'm using `flutter_markdown: ^0.6.10+4` in pubspec.yaml.

How can I adjust the line height but keep `selectable: true`?